# Swapping two numbers with while loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'd like to get `[[2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 2]]` from `[1, 2, 3]` in Ruby.

For `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, I'd like to get [[2, 1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3]]

Rule: Within two numbers, if left one is smaller then it swap the position.

I have the following codes so far but it returns `[[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]`

What am I doing wrong here? I appreciate any inputs.

In amidakuji.rb

```
class Amidakuji
  def initialize(column, rung)
    @column = column
    @rung = rung
    @myarr = []
    @per_arr = []
    @build_arr = []
  end

  def build_initial
    @arr = (1..@column).to_a
  end

  def swap_element 
    i = 0
    arr = build_initial
    while i < @column - 1 do
      @build_arr << swap(arr, i)
      i += 1
    end
    @build_arr
  end

  def swap(arr, a)
    if arr[a] < arr[a + 1]
      arr[a], arr[a + 1] = arr[a + 1], arr[a]
    end
    arr
  end
end
```

In amidakuji_spec.rb

```
    it 'should create an array with swapped elements' do
      expect(@kuji1.swap_element).to eq ([[2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 2]])
    end
```

Results

```
Failures:
   expected: [[2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 2]]
        got: [[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
```

Comment: Do you want a solution that only applies to arrays containing three elements, and if so, you do just want to swap the first two elements, then swap the last two?  If you want it to apply to arrays with more than three elements you'll have clarify the rules for creating the result array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite compactly by using the methods [Enumerable#each_cons](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

**Code**

```
def doit(arr)
  (0...arr.size).each_cons(2).map do |i,j|
    a = arr.dup
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
    a
  end    
end
```

**Examples**

```
doit([1,2,3])     #=> [[2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 2]]
doit([1,2,3,4])   #=> [[2, 1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3]]
doit([1,2,3,4,5]) #=> [[2, 1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 2, 4, 5],
                  #=>  [1, 2, 4, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]]
```

**Explanation**

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]

b = (0...arr.size).each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: 0...4:each_cons(2)>
```

To view the contents of this enumerator:

```
b.to_a
  #=> [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Lastly

```
b.map do |i,j|
  a = arr.dup
  a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
  a
end
  #=> [[2, 1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3]]
```

In the last step, consider the first element of `b` that is passed to `map`, which assigns the following values to the block variables:

```
i => 0
j => 1
```

We then make a copy of `arr`, swap the elements offsets `0` and `1`, making

```
a => [2, 1, 3, 4]
```

and then enter `a` at the end of the block, causing `map` to replace `[0, 1]` with that array.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you're trying to accomplish and the output you're getting, it looks like you're reusing the same array when you want distinct arrays instead.  Specifically this line:

`@build_arr << swap(arr, i)`

is always passing the same 'arr' to swap.

So first time, it swaps the 1 and the 2 to give you [2, 1, 3]
Second time, it swaps the 1 and the 3 give you [2, 3, 1]

You push the same array onto @build_arr twice, which is why it repeats.